# How to Get the Dual Sim Mobile Number?

Tags: android, dual-sim

I want to get the mobile number from a different sim. Dual sim number is saved in a different variable.

Some people give answer like:

```
TelephonyManager tm =(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

I also give the permission in the Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

but it didn't work, all time `number` variable give ("") value. So please provide mw with a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `tm.getLine1Number()` returns null or "" try to use `tm.getSubscriberId()` it always worked for me.

```
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
if (number == null || number.equals("")) {
    number = tm.getSubscriberId();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir, i don't get mobile number...

Result is :- 405868052479493

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the Subscription Manager for minSdkVersion 22 onwards :)

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SubscriptionManager mSubscriptionManager = SubscriptionManager.from(getBaseContext());
        List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptions = mSubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();


        for(SubscriptionInfo subscriptionInfo: subscriptions) {
            Log.v("SIM", subscriptionInfo.getNumber());
        }


    }
```

Comment: sir, i don't get value of my mobile number....

I have Dual sim mobile my first sim response like this :- 

{id=2, iccId=89918680400068704945 simSlotIndex=0 displayName=Jio 4G carrierName=Jio 4G nameSource=2 iconTint=-16746133 dataRoaming=0 iconBitmap=android.graphics.Bitmap@3cdba36c mcc 405 mnc 868 mSubStatus=1 mNwMode=9}

Comment: @ShubhamMaheshwari  i got this problem too,  subscriptionInfo.getNumber() return null;